# How to use If statements with Boolean and to read user input

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

I did a post yesterday about this problem but was completely wrong with how i wrote so ive spent the night and this morning trying again and still cant get my head around how to do it.

What i'm trying to do is test my `IsInRoom` method by getting the user to input two coordinates i cant figure out how to get the user input read by the IF statement and everytime is use `r.IsInRoom` it comes up with an error saying "the method `IsInRoom(Point)` in the type room is not applicable for the arguments double.

I have tried so many different ways of doing this and everytime i keep ending up back in the same place. if any one has any ideas that would be great im really new to java so would be great if you could give me some pointers on how to use these functions properly?

Ive made the changes to the If else statement but in getting this error

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at CurtisBaldwin.buildingconsole.Room.isInRoom(Room.java:85)
   at aCurtisBaldwin.buildingconsole.Room.main(Room.java:115)
```

i think this is because ive not assigned the user input to the if statement? but im not sure how you do that

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.io.Reader;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Random;

public class Room {
    private static int X; 
    private static int Y; 
    private static Point P; 
    private int[] coords;
    Random ranGen;

    public Room(String rstr) {
        StringSplitter S = new StringSplitter(rstr, " ");
        coords = S.getIntegers();
    }

    public Point getRandomPoint (Random ranGen) {
        return new Point(coords[0] +1 + ranGen.nextInt(coords[2] - coords[0] -2), (coords[1] +1 + ranGen.nextInt(coords[3] - coords[1] -2)));                                               
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Room " + coords[0] + ", " + coords[1] + ", " + coords[2] + ", " + coords[3] + " Door " + coords[4] + ", " + coords[5];
    }

    public boolean IsInRoom(Point xy) {
        P = new Point (X,Y);

        return (xy.getX() > coords[0] && xy.getX() < coords[2] && xy.getY() > coords[1] && xy.getY() < coords[3]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Room r = new Room("0 0 5 5 0 2"); // create room
        System.out.println(r.toString()); // and print it

        String userIn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
            (null, "please enter two coordinates one X and one Y separated by a space");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, r.IsInRoom(P) + userIn);

        if (r.IsInRoom(P.getX() ) ) {
            System.out.println( (int) P.getX() + "," + (int) P.getY() + "Is in room");
        }
        else if (r.IsInRoom(P.getY() ) ){
            System.out.println((int) P.getX() + "," + (int) P.getY() + "Is in room");
        else (r.IsInRoom(P.getXY() ) ) { 
            System.out.println ((int) P.getX() + "," + (int) P.getY() + "Is not in room");
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: While the error is pretty obvious, there's a big problem with how you designed the class. For example the fact that you keep state inside class members but still send it around in methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states what's wrong. Your `isInRoom` method expects a `Point` parameter, but in your `if(r.isInRoom(P.getX()))` or `if(r.isInRoom(P.getY()))` the `getX()` and `getY()` are `double` types, which is why your get the error..

Simply changing your if-else construction to this:

```
if(r.isInRoom(P)){
  System.out.println((int)P.getX() + "," + (int)P.getY() + "Is in room");
} else{
  System.out.println((int)P.getX() + "," + (int)P.getY() + "Is not in room");
}
```

Is enough to fix it.

PS: Methods and variables are usually in camelCase, so `IsInRoom` should be `isInRoom`. It's not a requirement, but it's best practice for Java programming.

Comment: hi thank you for your help with fixing my If else statement, how do i go about linking the user input as im currently getting an error 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
on lines 113 and 85 which is the return statement on the isInRoom method and the joptionpane.showmessagedialog etc

Comment: i also went through and changed the name of IsInRoom to isInRoom

Answer (score 1):

You did this mistake

`P.getX()` and `P.getY()` return `double` but in `IsInRoom` argument you are expecting `Point` :)

another point is that till java 11 we didn't support argument in else block like you did eg:

```
else (r.IsInRoom(P.getXY() ) )
```

Comment: Thanks for your help i appreciate it